# WebStorm: how to rename html attribute?

Tags: html, webstorm

I have imgs with `src` attribute. But since I'm moving to lazy loading all of my imgs. I would like to change `src` to `data-original` for all of my images. But it seems I can't simply select `src` in the html file and do a "Refactor | Rename".

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Standard find & replace should do the job.

Comment: Tried ctrl+R -> `src` in first field/`data-original` in second?